# Box shadow gets cutoff by parent div on safari

Tags: css, debugging, svg, safari

I have a problem with this box shadow on safari where it is cutoff by the  tag & won't extend past it.

Note: this problem is only on safari, all the other browsers are completely fine.

*Side note I have tried using position:relative with z-index and overflow:visible on all the parent elements and nothing changed.*

***P.S. I can't use padding as it will break the layout.***

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
        <div class="icons">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohamed-aly-a3a781213/" class="socials" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="linkedin">
                <svg class="smalliconsquare" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-11 19h-3v-11h3v11zm-1.5-12.268c-.966 0-1.75-.79-1.75-1.764s.784-1.764 1.75-1.764 1.75.79 1.75 1.764-.783 1.764-1.75 1.764zm13.5 12.268h-3v-5.604c0-3.368-4-3.113-4 0v5.604h-3v-11h3v1.765c1.396-2.586 7-2.777 7 2.476v6.759z"/>
                    <defs>
                        <radialGradient id="Solid">
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#6c6f7c"/>
                        </radialGradient>
                        <radialGradient id="RadialGradient1" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.4" fx="0.75" fy="0.75"
                        spreadMethod="reflect">
                            <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#b75aba"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#42c0ff"/>
                        </radialGradient>
                    </defs>
                </svg>
            </a>
            <div class="emptyspace"></div>
            <a href="https://github.com/Metwesh" class="socials" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="github">
                <svg class="smalliconcircle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z"/>
                    <radialGradient id="RadialGradient2" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.4" fx="0.75" fy="0.75"
                        spreadMethod="reflect">
                        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#b75aba"/>
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#42c0ff"/>
                    </radialGradient>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

SCSS

```
.contentfoot{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px 40px;
    background-color: $black;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    overflow-wrap: unset;

        @include breakpoint-down(medium){
            padding: 20px 0;
        }

}

.icons{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;


        @include breakpoint-down(small){
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
}

.socials{
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}


.smalliconsquare{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    fill:url(#Solid);
    overflow: visible;


    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;    
    transition: -webkit-box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;    
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;    
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;    
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;        
    @include breakpoint-down(small){
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        @include breakpoint-down(xsmall){
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
        }
}

.emptyspace{
    height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;

        @include breakpoint-down(medium){
            display: none;
        }
}

.socials:last-child{
    border-radius: 70px;
}


.smalliconcircle{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    fill:url(#Solid);
    overflow: visible;


    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;    
    transition: -webkit-box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;    
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;   
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;     
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;        
        @include breakpoint-down(small){
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        @include breakpoint-down(xsmall){
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
        }

}
a.socials:first-child:hover{
    .smalliconsquare{
        fill:url(#RadialGradient1);
        -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
    }
}

a.socials:last-child:hover{
    .smalliconcircle{
        fill:url(#RadialGradient1);
        -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black, 0 0 10px $purplish, 0 0 15px $blueish, 0 0 20px $cyan, 0 0 25px $lightpink;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by putting the box-shadow on the parent  tag and sized it according to the svg with the proper border-radius

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).